# Getting a dbid by table name

Tags: quickbase

As far as I know, all QuickBase API calls are called using the following syntax: `http://<quickbase>/db/<dbid>?`

Is there a way to get the dbid field without navigating to that database table within QuickBase?

If the above is not possible, would anyone recommend anything other than creating another table that stores the IDs of the tables you want?

With the latter method, I believe I would only need to store one dbid and could pull down the rest (which I believe would still need to be user entered, but would be better than requiring them to change the code).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[API_GetSchema](http://www.quickbase.com/api-guide/getschema.html)** will return the list of dbids.

```
https://www.quickbase.com/db/<yourApplicationId>?act=API_GetSchema&apptoken=<yourApplicationTokenId>&fmt=flat
```